# Javascript set required library as module export for purposes of inheritance

Tags: javascript, class

One small request before I begin. Please hold back on the "classes are syntax sugar" responses. That could turn my question to a place where I don't actually get an answer. I get the idea on that and this is a specialized project where classes are a must.

What I am doing is setting up a convenience class that is used to include common libraries in several other classes; ex: loggers, etc...

The idea is to setup a general class with required libraries assigned to class properties, and have other classes extend the general class and receive the required libraries.

I have this working. The question is if it is a bad idea or practice to setup class inheritance for this purpose?

```
 // base_class.js
    const SomeUtility = require('../common/utility/utility');
    
        class BaseClass {
            constructor() {
                this.SomeUtility = SomeUtility;
            }
        }
        
    //api_class.js
    const BaseClass = require('./base_class.js');
        class APIClass extends BaseClass {
            constructor() {
                super();
            }
        
            apiCall(req, res) {
                this.SomeUtility.logReq(req); //super.SomeUtility also works...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Usually opinionated posts get closed here, as there's no one true right way. However, I would suggest you read up on "composition over inheritance". You don't need to inherit to do this. If you don't want to include a _bunch_ of stuff every time, it's still better to combine these utilities in 1 object, include the object but _don't_ make them part of your inheritance structure. If you're not using `this`, a class is probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That is great to know on the opinionated posts.  When you say combine them into one object, are you meaning export an object literal with references to each library? Many are separate packages.

Comment: I think the key here is still composition vs inheritance. Classes should ideally encapsulate 1 responsibility. If you need to do a certain type of API call often, make a function somewhere that does this and include the function.

There's definitely no need/benefit to be able to do `this.apiCall` instead of just `apiCall`. If you come from Java or PHP it's tempted to think of everything as a class, but it's often considered better to just use functions for everything *unless* you have a good case for class. Don't make classes your default building block.

Comment: Aside: anyone who dismisses a feature as 'syntax sugar' is not worth listening to. Syntax sugar is a _good_ thing if it makes things clearer/shorter.

Comment: Evert, your right on the function approach. Hearing you say it, I realize that is exactly what I did on my error handlers for the app. 1 class with static methods to call handlers of various types. Thank you, I rarely reach out here, but the approach nagged me...felt wrong :)

Comment: You also don't need a class with static methods. Do you have a Java or PHP background? Just make functions =)

Comment: I do have that background, but in this case it's a requirement to use classes. Out of my control. :)